PyArrow error while using Streamlit agraph component
While running 'https://github.com/ChrisDelClea/streamlit-agraph/examples/karate_club_graph.py' as is, got following error:
StreamlitAPIException: To use Custom Components in Streamlit, you need to install PyArrow. To do so locally:

pip install pyarrow

And if you're using Streamlit Cloud, add "pyarrow" to your requirements.txt.

Traceback:
File "karate_club_graph.py", line 30, in <module>
    return_value = agraph(nodes=nodes,
File "...envs\genai\lib\site-packages\streamlit_agraph\__init__.py", line 38, in agraph
    component_value = _agraph(data=data_json, config=config_json)

I do have pyarrow installed, but still ..
How to fix?

I uninstalled the existing with pip uninstall streamlit, then reinstalled it with conda install -c conda-forge streamlit, this seems to work
